# Windows Batch File can't use variable in for syntax

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I want to use a variable skip parameter in for loop, but it won't let me do it.
Here is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p testcase=<testcases.txt
set /a end=%testcase%*13

for /L %%P IN (1,13,%end%) DO (

    set skip=skip=%%P
    echo !skip!
    set vidx=0

    for /f "%skip%" %%A in (testcases.txt) do (
        set /a vidx=!vidx! + 1
        set var!vidx!=%%A
    )
)
```

Here skip is skip=1, but it doesn't skip any line. When I replace it with skip=1. then it works fine, but I want to skip variable no. of lines in each iteration. Please help.

Comment: Is this a typo: should be `"!skip!"` instead of `"%skip%"`?

Comment: Tried using that as well, it said "!skip!" was unexpected at this time."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with this logic the only option is a subroutine:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p testcase=<testcases.txt
set /a end=%testcase%*13

for /L %%P IN (1,13,%end%) DO (

    set skip=skip=%%P
    echo !skip!
    set vidx=0
    call :innerFor %%P

)

exit /b 0

:innerFor
    for /f "skip=%~1" %%A in (testcases.txt) do (
        set /a vidx=!vidx! + 1
        set var!vidx!=%%A
    )
 exit /b 0
```

parametrization of `FOR /F` options is a little bit tricky..
Though I have no the content of your files I cant test if this works correctly .

Comment: The file is a simple one. The first line contains an integer T i.e. the no. of test cases. T test cases follows. Each test case has 13 lines containing one integer in each.

Comment: @DarkNemesis - it's because how `FOR /F` parses its options.1)The parameters/tokens are always (`%%A`) are always expanded even after delayed expansion variables.2) When the `FOR` meets a `%%` in batch file it takes it for a parameter/token definition which is with higher prio than options - which brokes the command. Looks like command line arguments are expanded before the FOR tokens so with subroutine it works.